# Anaconda or/and PIP

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have installed my packages via Anaconda and pip so far. Unfortunately, this has often led to inconsistencies in the past and the installations were tedious and annoying. I want to improve something with my new computer and am now considering whether I should do everything via pip and do without anaconda completely.
How do you do it? Do you mix anaconda and pip?
Do you only create the environments with anaconda and then install everything with pip?
What would you advise me to do?

Thanks a lot!

masterkey

Comment: This is opinion-based and therefore off topic, but generally speaking I wouldn't recommend installing Python packages into the same environment using different tools.

Comment: I use conda and install packages with conda. It is also reasonable to use conda to create environments and install packages with pip. It is also reasonable to not use conda. I suppose there are many other reasonable things (whether mixing conda and pip is one of them I'm not sure - I wouldn't say it doesn't work but it is probably something that will continue to improve as being able to use pip with conda is a goal of conda - reference: [using-pip-in-a-conda-environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) ).